# spring-boot tomcat access log rotation by size

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

Is it possible to rotate tomcat access logs based on size? Going through the [Appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), I couldn't find such an option. These are the only access log options I'm seeing:

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.buffered=true # Whether to buffer output such that it is flushed only periodically.
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=logs # Directory in which log files are created. Can be absolute or relative to the Tomcat base dir.
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=false # Enable access log.
server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=.yyyy-MM-dd # Date format to place in the log file name.
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=common # Format pattern for access logs.
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=access_log # Log file name prefix.
server.tomcat.accesslog.rename-on-rotate=false # Whether to defer inclusion of the date stamp in the file name until rotate time.
server.tomcat.accesslog.request-attributes-enabled=false # Set request attributes for the IP address, Hostname, protocol, and port used for the request.
server.tomcat.accesslog.rotate=true # Whether to enable access log rotation.
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log # Log file name suffix.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that with the out of the box Tomcat. But there are a couple of options.

a) Disable tomcat's rotation completely by setting `server.tomcat.accesslog.rotate` as false, then do the rotation using another utility like unix's [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) which does support rotating by size. Use the `copytruncate` option to avoid restarting tomcat.

b) Implement a custom [AccessLogValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve.html) and override the `rotate()` method to customize rotation as you want. Then inject this valve using [addContextValves](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.0.0.RC3/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/tomcat/TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.html#addContextValves(Valve...)) in TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory (you can find an example of customizing TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43653845/spring-boot-1-3-5-tomcat-access-log-rotation)). You'll also have to remove the default implementation from the list returned by [getValves](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/tomcat/TomcatReactiveWebServerFactory.html#getEngineValves--).

Answer (score 0):

By default, Tomcat doesn't provide access log rotation based on size, though you can configure hourly/monthly etc. configuration using file date format using `server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format`. for example hourly

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=.yyyy-MM-dd.HH
```

If you still need to rotate based on size only, you can extend `Access Log Valve`. check [tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Extended_Access_Log_Valve) or refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278614/how-to-rotate-the-tomcat-localhost-log)